Calculate total percentage with total N and events in two data frames in R
Working with some event data from a dataset that has multiple different courses across multiple semesters. I need to find out how many students "logged" into the course each week and then find the percentage of the course that logged in.
Below is some sample code:
events <- data.frame(student_id= c(101, 101, 101, 
                         102, 102, 102,
                         155, 155, 155,
                         101, 101), 
             event_date=as.Date(c("11/09/2000","11/10/2000","11/12/2000",
                            "11/09/2000","11/10/2000", "11/12/2000",
                            "11/09/2001","11/14/2001","11/15/2001",
                            "11/09/2001","11/15/2001"), "%m/%d/%Y"), 
             course_id=c(111,111,122,
                         111,111,111,
                         122,122,122,
                         111,111),
             term=c("Fall 2000","Fall 2000", "Fall 2000",
                    "Fall 2000","Fall 2000", "Fall 2000",
                    "Fall 2001","Fall 2001", "Fall 2001",
                    "Fall 2001","Fall 2001"))

Calculation for daily events:
daily_events <- events %>%
  mutate(daily_event_count = ymd(event_date)) %>%
  group_by(course_id, term, week=week(event_date)) %>%
  reframe(total_events = n_distinct(event_date),
            stud_event_count = n_distinct(student_id)) 

Now I want to find out what percentage of the course "logged in" on any given week. I did some hard coding to get it to run but I know there is a better way to do this, right? This is okay since my sample data has only two courses, but in reality I have many.
Below is the mutate command I added with an ifelse statement:
daily_events <- events %>%
  mmutate(daily_event_count = ymd(event_date)) %>%
  group_by(course_id, term, week=week(event_date)) %>%
  reframe(total_events = n_distinct(event_date),
            stud_event_count = n_distinct(student_id)) %>% 
  mutate(stud_pct = ifelse(course_id==111 & term=='Fall 2000', (stud_event_count/2)*100,
                           ifelse(course_id==122 & term=='Fall 2000', (stud_event_count/1)*100,0)))

I calculated the total number of distinct students in another query, i.e. where the 2 and 1 are coming from.
stud_distr <- events %>%
  group_by(term, course_id) %>%
  reframe(stud_count = n_distinct(student_id))

How can I get the percentage when I have a lot more data and an ifelse or case/when seems inefficient?

Do you really need to compute daily_event_count? The variable name doesn't reflect the new values, and you don't use it later. Even if you use it in your full code, it would be better to remove it here.

Something like this:
daily_events_2 <- events %>% 
  mutate(week = week(event_date)) %>% 
  mutate(stud_count = n_distinct(student_id), 
         .by = c(term, course_id)) %>% 
  summarise(total_events = n_distinct(event_date),
            stud_event_count = n_distinct(student_id),
            .by = c(course_id, term, week, stud_count)) %>% 
  mutate(stud_pct = stud_event_count / stud_count * 100)

I rarely use reframe. Instead use summarise if I need to combine the data into a single row, or mutate to return the same number of rows.
The code runs in 3 steps: (1) compute the total number of distinct students for each term and course without changing the other data, (2) compute the counts and (3) compute the percents.

this is great. Thank you for saving me from a bunch of hard coding
